# JTAppleCalendar Custom cell bug on cellForItemAt date in Swift 3.2

Tags: swift, swift3, calendar, swift4, jtapplecalendar

I added `JTAppleCalendar` inside my project and I want to add some tags in some of my calendar cells. I have success adding them, but when I scroll left or right on my calendar months, cells inside tags disappear, hide, or mix, and when I scroll again and again there is more and more mixing. Do I need any protocols or delegates, etc.? Or, it is just a bug?

> How can I fix that bug?

[My example GitHub project](https://github.com/LetSwiftDev/CalendarBug)

My `cellForItemAt` code:

```
func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {
        let cell = calendar.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellView", for: indexPath) as! CellView

        var currentdate = String(describing: myCalendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: cellState.date))
        currentdate = currentdate.substring(from: 9, length: 10)


        cell.tagList.tags.removeAll()
        cell.tagList.hide()
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
        cell.tagList.alpha = 0
        cell.tagList.numberOfRows = 0
        cell.tagList.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.tagList.isHidden = true


        var i : Int
        i = 0

        for object in datas {

        i =  i + 1

                let clean = "\(object)".components(separatedBy: "*")

                if clean[0] == currentdate {
                   let gotag : Int
                    gotag = Int(clean[1])!
                    cell.tagList.isHidden = false
                    cell.dayLabel.text = cellState.text
                    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

                    let itemName = "Item name  \(i)"


                        cell.tagList.alpha = 1

                        if clean[1] == "1" {

                                cell.tagList.addTag(itemName, target: self, tapAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)), longPressAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)),backgroundColor: UIColor.orange,textColor: UIColor.white,comesTag: gotag)


                        }else if clean[1] == "2" {

                                cell.tagList.addTag(itemName, target: self, tapAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)), longPressAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)),backgroundColor: UIColor.green,textColor: UIColor.white,comesTag: gotag)

                        }else if clean[1] == "3" {

                                 cell.tagList.addTag(itemName, target: self, tapAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)), longPressAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)),backgroundColor: UIColor.brown,textColor: UIColor.white,comesTag: gotag)

                        }else if clean[1] == "4" {

                              cell.tagList.addTag(itemName, target: self, tapAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)), longPressAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)),backgroundColor: UIColor.black,textColor: UIColor.white,comesTag: gotag)
                        }



            }else{

                cell.tagList.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }





        }


        handleCellConfiguration(cell: cell, cellState: cellState)
        return cell
    }
```

Bug in action:

https://github.com/LetSwiftDev/CalendarBug/blob/master/calendarbug.gif

[image]

**Also you can join official JTAppleCalendar chat here**
https://gitter.im/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, to make a weird "workaround" you should implement the classic **UICollectionView** (JTAppleCalendar comes from it) `willDisplay` [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview?language=objc), that , as you can see , in theory it should be used to detect cell additions instead of replicate it's content, so to make this re-build of content you can follow the example also explained to the **JTAppleCalendar** [gitHub](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) [issues](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues/553) and **reported by swift nub [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487437/1894067) in this page**.

So, your code could be:

### **ViewController.swift**:

```
extension ViewController: JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate, JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource {
    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplay cell: JTAppleCell, forItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var cell = cell as! CellView
        cell = sharedFunctionToConfigureCell(cell: cell, cellState: cellState, date: date)
    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {
        var cell = calendar.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellView", for: indexPath) as! CellView
        cell = sharedFunctionToConfigureCell(cell: cell, cellState: cellState, date: date)
        return cell
    }

    func sharedFunctionToConfigureCell(cell: CellView, cellState: CellState, date: Date)-> CellView {
        var currentdate = String(describing: myCalendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: cellState.date))
        currentdate = currentdate.substring(from: 9, length: 10)
        cell.tagList.tags.removeAll()
        cell.tagList.hide()
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil
        cell.tagList.alpha = 0
        cell.tagList.numberOfRows = 0
        cell.tagList.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        cell.tagList.isHidden = true
        var i : Int
        i = 0
        for object in datas {
            i =  i + 1
            let clean = "\(object)".components(separatedBy: "*")
            if clean[0] == currentdate {
                let gotag : Int
                gotag = Int(clean[1])!
                cell.tagList.isHidden = false
                cell.dayLabel.text = cellState.text
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
                let itemName = "Item name  \(i)"
                cell.tagList.alpha = 1
                if clean[1] == "1" {
                    cell.tagList.addTag(itemName, target: self, tapAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)), longPressAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)),backgroundColor: UIColor.orange,textColor: UIColor.white,comesTag: gotag)
                }else if clean[1] == "2" {
                    cell.tagList.addTag(itemName, target: self, tapAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)), longPressAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)),backgroundColor: UIColor.green,textColor: UIColor.white,comesTag: gotag)
                }else if clean[1] == "3" {
                    cell.tagList.addTag(itemName, target: self, tapAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)), longPressAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)),backgroundColor: UIColor.brown,textColor: UIColor.white,comesTag: gotag)
                }else if clean[1] == "4" {
                    cell.tagList.addTag(itemName, target: self, tapAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)), longPressAction: #selector(ViewController.tap(_:)),backgroundColor: UIColor.black,textColor: UIColor.white,comesTag: gotag)
                }
            }else{
                cell.tagList.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
        }
        handleCellConfiguration(cell: cell, cellState: cellState)
        return cell
    }

    // your other code..
```

### Update (after your tests):

After your comments, I've decided to analyze in deep your code.

First of all, there is a little bug in your mainStoryBoard and you can easily correct it replacing `DesignableButton` (unexistent class) with `UIButton` as showed in this pic to avoid the error :  **`CalendarBug[9879:1645088] Unknown class _TtC11CalendarBug16DesignableButton in Interface Builder file`**.

[image]

After, the full `JTAppleCaledar` library seems hasn't any problem, in fact the author have extended also the `willDisplay` delegate that solved many issues around rendering of cells.

I've found your problem in the `TagListView.swift` class, more precisely in the method `reset`.

### TagListView.swift:

```
func reset() {
  for tag in tags {
      tag.removeFromSuperview()
  }
  tags = []
  currentRow = 0
  numberOfRows = 0
}
```

This method remove all the tags list (the array of labels) from superview but not the other tags added in past to the superview, in other words only tags contained in the array `tags`. So, to avoid this issue you can reinforce your `reset` method by adding on line (we know they are `UILabel` so it's not needed to know all their `tag` number):

```
func reset() {
  for tag in tags {
      tag.removeFromSuperview()
  }
  tags = []
  currentRow = 0
  numberOfRows = 0
  self.subviews.forEach({ if $0 is UILabel { $0.removeFromSuperview()} })
}
```

To optimize your code you simply correct this method as:

```
func reset(){
    tags = []
    currentRow = 0
    numberOfRows = 0
    self.subviews.forEach({ if $0 is UILabel { $0.removeFromSuperview()} })
}
```

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Mate I will test tonight after I will turn you . thanks for answer. If ok I will approve.

Comment: dude, I added that codes into ViewController on example GitHub project inside and I scrolled left month after right month again again like gif , and same issue again mixing tags. doesn't work. you can download example github project after add that codes inside view controller you will see.

Comment: I think maybe need to delegate tag lists ? in TagListView to inside sharedFunctionToConfigureCell

Comment: Do you know what is exactly the JTAppleCalendar version you try to test with your github project:currently the latest sources is tagged v.7.1.4

Comment: I added Carthage support in example project after I updated again latest 7.1.4 you can download it now.

Comment: https://gitter.im/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar here framework owner on chat if you need any question you can ask him

Comment: I've update my code, take a look and let me know. I've maded some tests and now it seems ok.

Comment: i will check after I will turn.

Comment: @Alesandro Ornano can you upload working codes to GitHub I will approve and after I will update GitHub everyone can use after thats.

Comment: thank you worked fine, but please update with Carthage.. so using. Carthage. I approved. now you have + 300 reps.

Comment: Umh, are you sure is a right idea? I've removed carthage to permit all the people to download and test immediately your project without third part tools. If I re-put this tool many people could have problem with compile or run it due to carthrage versions that nothing have to do with this bug. Anyway, If you put the code here in this answer to your github version you have my same results.

Comment: yeah, but im using Carthage , if  with Carthage or cocoa pods thats codes work success no problem.

Comment: Ok let me the time to add it, I'll upload a version also with carthage to another folder in my github to have both versions ;-)

Comment: All right , did it. It works correctly. You can download it always from : https://github.com/aornano/CalendarBug (the folder name is WithCarthage)

Comment: @Alessanro Ornano, Thank you man, I think will help many people, if need any swift update you can do. Follow, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the true issue, but you missed a function.
Implement the `willDisplayCell` function as shown here -> https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar/issues/553

This might resolve your problem.
but it is weird that you custom frame work doesn't warn you that you forgot to implement that function.

Comment: which code will be add ? can you fix it with my codes ? which codes will be add in my codes ? can you answer

Comment: The answer is found on the link i posted. The function is called `willDisplayCell` and that link i posted explains how to implement it. Basically the willDisplay cell function will have exactly the same code as your `cellForItem` function

Comment: can you add codes into your answer i will test after if ok , i will aprove your answer and will help many people thank you

Comment: I responded to your question on github

Comment: @iOSCalendarViewOnMyProfile when I adding that codes gives me Extra argument 'date' in call

Comment: @SwiftDeveloper there is no code related to the calendar I can give that will fix this, because the bug is not in the library. I could help you more, but i do not understand your code. Can you make your code simpler of github so that I can help? Make your code the simplest until you see the problem happening.